# Pubsub-style notify/handler in Ansible (restart all services using source code when it changes)

Tags: ansible

I have a role that updates source code of my project from git, let name it `source_tree`. Git repository contains source used by multiple services so I want to *restart all services using that source on each host if change in git is detected*.

I.e.:

```
- git: repo=ssh://git@github.com/mylogin/hello.git dest=/home/mylogin/hello
  notify: restart everything dependent on source code
```

For example, I have roles `webapp`, `notification_service`, `celery`. A host can have any set of such roles, for example first server runs `webapp`, second runs both `notification_service` and `celery`. All these services use source code from the same directory.

Problem is:

- I can't list all handlers in `notify` such as:

  ```
  - git: repo=ssh://git@github.com/mylogin/hello.git dest=/home/mylogin/hello
    notify: 
      - restart webapp
      - restart notification service
      - restart celery
  ```

  Because playbook will fail with error if I run playbook without all of roles (or even if host don't include all of roles):

  `ERROR: change handler (restart celery) is not defined`

  (I.e. I have `webapp.yml` playbook that includes `source_tree` and `webapp` roles, but not `notification_service` and `celery`.)

  And there's no way to ignore this error.
- I can't create multiple handlers with the same name, only one (defined last) will be in effect.

How to overcome these limitations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this across roles, but you could try registering results of the git task

```
- git: repo=ssh://git@github.com/mylogin/hello.git dest=/home/mylogin/hello
  register: gitrc
```

Then read it from each of the roles. For example,

in `webapp/tasks/main.yml`:

```
- supervisorctl: name=uwsgi state=restarted
  when: gitrc|changed
```

in `celery/tasks/main.yml`:

```
- supervisorctl: name=celery state=restarted
  when: gitrc|changed
```

Of course, these become tasks instead of handlers.

Comment: Seems that it works. Also, it's possible to convert tasks to handlers again by creating task with "debug" action and "notify" that just prints message and notifies handler.